# How to make threads synchronize in a loop statement?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am new to threads. I am trying to load a small array of photos. Right now I am using Async tasks/ threads, but how do I make the outcome sequential? Below is an illustration:

What I want:

```
a[0] = photo1;
a[1] = photo2;
a[2] = photo3;
a[3] = photo4
```

What my program gives me instead. Note that the order changes and is random:

```
a[0] = photo[2];
a[1] = photo[1];
a[2] = etc
```

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < mNoOfContacts; i++) {
    String stringContactUri = storeSettings.getString("contactUri"+i, "");
    if (stringContactUri != ""){
        Uri contactUri = Uri.parse(stringContactUri);
        loadContactInfo(contactUri);
    }
...
private void loadContactInfo(Uri contactUri) {

    AsyncTask<Uri, Void, ContactInfo> task = new AsyncTask<Uri, Void, ContactInfo>() {

        @Override
        protected ContactInfo doInBackground(Uri... uris) {             
            return mContactAccessor.loadContact(getContentResolver(), uris[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ContactInfo result) {
            Contacts[mNoOfContacts] = result;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mNoOfContacts+"Picked Contact"+Contacts[mNoOfContacts].getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mNoOfContacts++;
        } 
    };

    task.execute(contactUri);
}
...
```

My code is a modification of the Google Android demo app - Business Cards.
Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What might be the easiest thing to do is make the `onPostExecute` method call a routine that does the sorting: pass both the ContactInfo and the Uri and then compare the Uri with the original and put it in the proper place.

Alternatively modify your `AsyncTask` so instead of launching one per Uri you launch one you pass all the `Uri`s at once and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that, by definition, "Asynchronous Tasks" are not synchronized...Asynchronous literally means "not synchronized." If you want it synchronized, just load them the old fashioned way by doing a URI call, get your photo and do it again once the last photo was loaded.